# How to DROP a column from a table in MySQL using a column number

Tags: mysql, handsontable

I am trying to remove a column from a MySQL table that I am using with Handsontable. When I remove a column from the Handsontable, I can get the column's index using the `afterRemoveCol()` callback:

```
afterRemoveCol: function (index, amount) {
    alert(index +'  amount: '+amount);
}
```

I would like to remove the column using the column number (`n`) returned by this callback function from the MySQL table using something like:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Blah DROP COLUMN n;
```

So, if I want to drop column #3 from the MySQL table, How would I do this using just the column number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to RMathis answer, you can do everything within SQL by also using SET to define the DROP string in conjuntion with [PREPARE and EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43133/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`col1` varchar(1), 
     `col2` varchar(1), 
     `col3` varchar(1), 
     `col4` varchar(1), 
     `col5` varchar(1))
;

set @col = (select column_name 
            from information_schema.columns 
            where table_name='table1' and ordinal_position=3);

SET @s = CONCAT("alter table table1 drop column ", @col);

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Query 1**:

```
desc table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43133/1/0)**:

```
| COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_TYPE | IS_NULLABLE | COLUMN_KEY | COLUMN_DEFAULT | EXTRA |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|------------|----------------|-------|
|        col1 |  varchar(1) |         YES |            |         (null) |       |
|        col2 |  varchar(1) |         YES |            |         (null) |       |
|        col4 |  varchar(1) |         YES |            |         (null) |       |
|        col5 |  varchar(1) |         YES |            |         (null) |       |
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL from SQL can generate the drop statement using ordinal_position from information_schema.columns.

```
mysql test> create table test.tab (col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1), col4 char(1), col5 char(1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql test> desc test.tab;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col3  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col4  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col5  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This query is generating the statement to drop the third column...

```
mysql test> select concat('alter table ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' drop column ',column_name,';') as query1 from information_schema.columns where  table_schema='test' and table_name='tab' and ordinal_position=3;
+----------------------------------------+
| query1                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
| alter table test.tab drop column col3; |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now to run the projected command...

```
mysql test> alter table test.tab drop column col3;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The column definition has been removed from the table.

```
mysql test> desc test.tab;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col4  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col5  | char(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Worked!  "ordinal_position" was the key! I used your suggested solution to simply query the column name "WHERE ordinal_position=n". I then used the result to create my DROP statement using the column name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Name them (columns in your db mirroring the spreadsheet) with the numbers/letters in full correspondence with your spreadsheet.

And then you'd be able to use regular ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN.