# How to delete columns before a certain column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I remove a certain number of columns which occur before a certain column in a table using SQL. Suppose this is the schema of a student table:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| student_id | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gpa        | decimal(3,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| major      | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I want to delete 2 columns which occur before the column `major`, how could I do that by just **referencing the major column**

Comment: You want to remove only the data, or the columns too ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I want to delete the columns

Comment: You can find the position by `select TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA='your database' and TABLE_NAME='your table';`

Comment: If your use case for this request is anything except "I am curious if something that, in the real world, shall never ever be done, can be done somehow", then you might want to rethink your use case. Nevertheless, if you want to try, you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42635314).